# Importing module from subfolder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, python-module

This is the structure of my project

```
final
├── common
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── batch_data_processing.py
    ├── processing_utility.py
    ├── post_processing.py
├── Processing_raw_data
    ├── batch_process_raw_data.py
```

so i want to import from `common.batch_data_processing` in `batch_process_raw_data.py`

but when I try it I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'common'`

is there a way to import this module without the need to install it ?

Note : this is intended to be used by "non python users"

here is pictures to better discribe the problem.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code above your import code to indicate the path:

```py
# The following is a relative path, 
# it can also be replaced with the absolute path 
# of the directory where common is located.
# sys.path.append("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\Final")

import sys
sys.path.append("./")
```

[image]

*When all your scripts are in the same folder, importing modules is almost impossible to go wrong. If you need to import scripts from external folders, you can specify the path using the above method.*

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reproduce this and for your answer. I will flag it as the answer for this question. although I ended up using a .bat script to install the ```common``` package (in developement mode so I can still modiffy it) by using the command ```pip install -e``` in the common folder.